# Which Ubuntu (git) linux kernel tree matches my installed kernel?

Tags: kernel, git

Answering a [recent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481931/ubuntu-3-15-kernel-fix/481991#481991), and before that, trying to see if a [patch which is fundamental for my machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352836/how-can-i-tell-linux-kernel-to-completely-ignore-a-disk-as-if-it-was-not-even-co) had been included in a kernel release, I have found the following problem:

How can I match the kernel version I have for my kernel, which is

```
[:~] % uname -a
Linux samsung-romano 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with the exact kernel source, which I suppose should be stored in http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/linux.git;a=summary?

In that page there are quite a lot of tags, for example:

[image]

But none of them correspond to `3.13.0-29` which is my running kernel right now.

The mapping should be in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/ExtendedStable, where it is said that the 3.13 Ubuntu kernel is based on 3.13.11 --- I think. But from there to finding the tree I have installed is not straightforward.

The best options seems to go to `linux3.13-y.review` or  `linux3.13-y.queue`, but I am unable to find **where** this tree are marked for the release - if I understand well the policy, in `-review` the patches are accumulated for testing, and in `-queue` accumulated for the next minor release/update --- but I am unable to find the exact release tree. I mean, a tag equivalent to *`3.13.0-29` was cut here*.

Is that the tip of 
`linux3.13-y`? In this moment it is claiming it is `3.13.11.2`: where can I find a reference that links that number to the result of my `uname -a` (which is `3.13.0-29`)?

Notice: I know I can install the kernel source corresponding with my installed kernel. But I do not want to install them; I would like ti have a pointer to the git tree to be able to browse it online (and check for commits, patches, etc.).

Comment: I would personally go with [linux-3.13.y](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/linux.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/linux-3.13.y) or [linux-3.13.y-queue](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/linux.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/linux-3.13.y-queue).

Comment: @saiarcot895 yes --- thanks, I specified better. This is what I am doing now, and then guessing with the last build date of the kernel. But I am sure there should be a better, more direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository you are looking for is http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git;a=summary