# log checking after failing boot

Tags: log

This morning, my Linux workstation was dead. I tried to reboot
---> no hard disk found -- "Press F1 to continue"
---> F1 --> Ubuntu
---> works!

Can you tell me which log check after that Ubuntu fail to start?

Answer (score 1):

This `Press F1 to continue` looks like a BIOS message which means it has nothing to do with Ubuntu as the OS has not even started to boot at that time yet. Therefore you can not find it in any Ubuntu logs.

As far as I know, the BIOS usually does not have any error logs either, so you won't be able to investigate this further with the help of logs, unfortunately.

What you could do is to check your disk health/S.M.A.R.T. status (see e.g. [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/38566/367990) or [How do I check the health of a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/325283/367990)).

Other than this, you can only wait if the same error appears again and maybe reset your BIOS settings and replace the CMOS battery.

Answer (score 0):

....i spoke with the user and he told me the workstation crashed yesterday,...and on the next reboot he received the error... but i suppose because on the start the boot order checked for first to USB Storage. One USB was attached with no OS...

But Related to the crash of the system  what log i have to check?