# System freezes randomly, ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: freeze

I have these random freezes and I do not understand why, I have installed it on a SATA SSD drive, Kingston A400 480 GB.
this is the ubuntu log.

Please help me as I have no idea what is happening here!

```
  [   42.097388] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
  [   42.097400] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
  [   43.327972] rfkill: input handler disabled
  [  583.114350] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114362] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#7 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0f d1 e5 78 00 00 08 00
  [  583.114368] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 265414008
  [  583.114416] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114424] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0f d2 a4 b8 00 00 08 00
  [  583.114428] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 265462968
  [  583.114460] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114468] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 0f d7 6d 40 00 00 38 00
  [  583.114471] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 265776448
  [  583.114504] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114510] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#8 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 05 85 04 d8 00 00 40 00
  [  583.114514] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 92603608
  [  583.114546] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114553] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0f d6 6c 88 00 00 08 00
  [  583.114556] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 265710728
  [  583.114570] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3178501 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 33213842)
  [  583.114575] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 12682641
  [  583.114602] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114609] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#9 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 05 09 28 00 00 58 00
  [  583.114613] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 268765480
  [  583.114623] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3147349 (offset 0 size 45056 starting block 33595696)
  [  583.114627] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064485
  [  583.114645] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064486
  [  583.114651] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064487
  [  583.114657] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064488
  [  583.114678] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064489
  [  583.114684] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064490
  [  583.114698] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064491
  [  583.114715] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064492
  [  583.114722] Buffer I/O error on device sda3, logical block 13064493
  [  583.114761] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#12 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0f d6 6e b8 00 00 08 00
  [  583.114771] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 265711288
  [  583.114781] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3178502 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 33213912)
  [  583.114803] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_TIMEOUT
  [  583.114809] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#11 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0a c2 5e 00 00 01 90 00
  [  583.114812] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 180510208
  [  583.114822] EXT4-fs warning (device sda3): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 10 writing to inode 3178569 (offset 0 size 204800 starting block 22563826)
  [  583.117624] JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on sda3-8
```

results to fdisk -l

```
          Disk /dev/loop0: 153,7 MiB, 161198080 bytes, 314840 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop1: 14,5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop2: 339,1 MiB, 355614720 bytes, 694560 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop3: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop4: 153,8 MiB, 161214464 bytes, 314872 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop5: 192,5 MiB, 201789440 bytes, 394120 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop6: 1008 KiB, 1032192 bytes, 2016 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop7: 2,3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/sda: 447,1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          Disklabel type: gpt
          Disk identifier: 17A9DDEE-52F2-466B-BDB2-558E8AD7656E

          Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
          /dev/sda1       2048   7999487   7997440   3,8G Linux swap
          /dev/sda2    7999488 164249599 156250112  74,5G Linux filesystem
          /dev/sda3  164249600 351764479 187514880  89,4G Linux filesystem
          /dev/sda4  351764480 937699327 585934848 279,4G Microsoft basic data


          Disk /dev/sdb: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          Disklabel type: gpt
          Disk identifier: 09AB03D7-2EF7-48FD-B682-2C9DCADFB42B

          Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
          /dev/sdb1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
          /dev/sdb2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
          /dev/sdb3     567296 248427816 247860521 118,2G Microsoft basic data
          /dev/sdb4  248430592 250068991   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment


          Disk /dev/loop8: 4 MiB, 4214784 bytes, 8232 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop9: 53,7 MiB, 56315904 bytes, 109992 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop10: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop11: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop12: 143,5 MiB, 150470656 bytes, 293888 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop13: 89,3 MiB, 93581312 bytes, 182776 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop14: 3,7 MiB, 3846144 bytes, 7512 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop15: 14,8 MiB, 15458304 bytes, 30192 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop16: 3,7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop17: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop18: 35,3 MiB, 37027840 bytes, 72320 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop19: 374 MiB, 392163328 bytes, 765944 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop20: 34,6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop21: 91,1 MiB, 95522816 bytes, 186568 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


          Disk /dev/loop22: 372 MiB, 390045696 bytes, 761808 sectors
          Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
          Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
          I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

After a bad crash, and Facing the emergency mode, I managed to run "sudo fsck -f " on both mounts /sda2, and /sda3, sda3 had errors which were resolved and surprisingly, it came out of the emergency more.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 GiB, 1905045504 bytes, 3720792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 34.6 MiB, 36216832 bytes, 70736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 140.7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 17A9DDEE-52F2-466B-BDB2-558E8AD7656E

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   7999487   7997440   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda2    7999488 164249599 156250112  74.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  164249600 351764479 187514880  89.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  351764480 937699327 585934848 279.4G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 09AB03D7-2EF7-48FD-B682-2C9DCADFB42B

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     567296 248427816 247860521 118.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  248430592 250068991   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdc: 29.8 GiB, 32019316736 bytes, 62537728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0004319b

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 62537727 62535680 29.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck 0f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
Usage: fsck.ext4 [-panyrcdfktvDFV] [-b superblock] [-B blocksize]
        [-l|-L bad_blocks_file] [-C fd] [-j external_journal]
        [-E extended-options] [-z undo_file] device

Emergency help:
 -p                   Automatic repair (no questions)
 -n                   Make no changes to the filesystem
 -y                   Assume "yes" to all questions
 -c                   Check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list
 -f                   Force checking even if filesystem is marked clean
 -v                   Be verbose
 -b superblock        Use alternative superblock
 -B blocksize         Force blocksize when looking for superblock
 -j external_journal  Set location of the external journal
 -l bad_blocks_file   Add to badblocks list
 -L bad_blocks_file   Set badblocks list
 -z undo_file         Create an undo file
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda2: 744310/4890624 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 7710155/19531264 blocks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 3148043 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3148150 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3148274 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3151158 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3152299 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.

Inode 3153492 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3153506 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3155443 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3157259 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3157514 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3157714 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3158607 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3158625 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3158979 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3158988 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3161772 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3165110 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3165450 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3165452 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 3168674 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 3168710 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 3168743 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(12670580--12670583) -(12670588--12670591) -(12670596--12670599) -(13021304--13021307) -(13041027--13041035) -(13058217--13058220) -(13062617--13062620) -(13070585--13070588) -(13248791--13248794) -(13250398--13250401) -(13266401--13266404) -(13280499--13280506) -(13288704--13288707) -(13305340--13305343) -(13313719--13313723) -(13368964--13368967) -(13407343--13407346) -(13415160--13415170) -(13467534--13467537) -(13783866--13783869)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #386 (14022, counted=14034).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #397 (17946, counted=17959).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #398 (20697, counted=20709).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #404 (16579, counted=16591).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #405 (10012, counted=10024).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #406 (12725, counted=12734).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #407 (7595, counted=7599).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #409 (10975, counted=10990).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #410 (19312, counted=19316).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #420 (4329, counted=4333).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (18301771, counted=18301868).
Fix<y>? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -3148043 -3148150 -3148274 -3151158 -3152299 -3153492 -3153506 -3155443 -3157259 -3157514 -3157714 -3158607 -3158625 -3158979 -3158988 -3161772 -3165110 -3165450 -3165452 -3168674 -3168710 -3168743
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #384 (2, counted=9).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #385 (1373, counted=1382).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #386 (2270, counted=2276).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (5788262, counted=5788284).
Fix<y>? yes
y
/dev/sda3: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda3: 77188/5865472 files (4.2% non-contiguous), 5137492/23439360 blocks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -f /dev/sda3
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sda3: 77188/5865472 files (4.2% non-contiguous), 5137492/23439360 blocks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: You need to check that your new SSD firmware is up to date. You ARE having disk problems... or a bad SATA connection to the drive.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Edited the question. What do you mean by bad SATA connection, physically you mean?
Have to mention that this is a secondary drive I added to the empty SATA slot in my Asus S14 (S410 UN), it is held in place by screws to a metal rack, which is in turn screwed to the laptops body.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the physical SATA cable, or where it plugs in at either end. I put together a quick answer... things to check first. More will come later...

Comment: Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You may have a bad SATA cable, or SATA connection on the rear of the drive. What brand drive is this?
2. You have a lot of snap applications installed. They really slow things down, especially boot times.
3. Open the `Disks` app, select your hard drive, go to the "hamburger" icon, select `SMART Data & Tests`. Observe the data, take a screenshot, and put it on imgur.com for me to see. Then run the SMART tests.
4. Then, lets check your filesystem...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Go to https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager and download their `SSD Manager` app (requires Windows to run), and check your SSD firmware.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, been busy with studies. 
1. It is a kingston SA400S37480G

2. I am new to linux, will read into that

3. My system crashed very badly today, not passing the emergency mode no matter what I do. I managed to get up in recovery mode to get my codes and projects out before I do a fresh install.

4. I will try and see what this does. 

5. this piece of software indicates there is a C3 software update while I have C2 version, so I will update before I install a fresh batch.

Comment: see the update in question please, after the fsck command the system loaded again, after the crash i had today, which stated i was in emergency mode. I have put the results of the fsck in my post.

Comment: @NimaGhoroubi keep the fsck instructions for future reference. I didn't see your SMART Data screenshot. Load it to imgur.com. Please. Backup your important data, then update the SSD firmware asap. Report back.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay on image, https://imgur.com/Gpj2jxz, please tell me if there is any trouble seeing it. The temperature is wrong in this image, and wont change if i rerun the test. It shows a different temperature when I check the disk in terminal.
hddtemp shows this :
/dev/sda2: KINGSTON SA400S37480G: 25°C

Comment: second note, I updated firmware, and as you know ran the fsck, so far no lags or freezes, I read significant improvement in reaction time in the OS. Too soon to judge but it might have solved the issue. I will keep you posted here again if issues rise.

Comment: @NimaGhoroubi great news!

Comment: Thank you for your amazing work! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it could be because of bad sectors.

See if this would help - https://serverfault.com/questions/407007/what-do-these-disk-errors-in-syslog-mean

Or - [How do I check the health of a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325283/how-do-i-check-the-health-of-a-ssd)

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply. It is a brand new SSD, and I checked with SMART data and self test and there is no issues with the health of the drive.