# Can't Mount SSD (where windows and my files are located) Need to Save Files from there

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd, automount

I need to save some files from my personal computer but most of them are under windows user folder. With USB, I plugged in try ubuntu and can see my HDD but I can't access my SSD (where all files I need to save is located and where windows was). I am not well experienced with ubuntu. It can see the SSD on the left menu and when I try to open it, it tries but nothing happens. I went to disks and tried to mount a big partition from the SSD, it gave me the following error:
[image]

How I can access this disk and save my files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check the health of a SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325283/how-do-i-check-the-health-of-a-ssd)

Comment: Is Windows fast startup or hibernation on? Or bitlocker? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You may be able to mount read only. `sudo mkdir /media/windows` & 
`sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda3 /media/windows` Change sda3 example to your drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end it was my SSD (where windows was installed).0 It got corrupted data and whenever I tried to boot with windows usbs (3 in total with 3 different methods) it got stuck. And the reason for that was bootable win usb instances are always checking if there is a windows installed. Because my SSD was corrupted, it got stuck without showing anything. All that for that repair button.

**If you want to save your datas, Ubuntu bootable usb allows you to try ubuntu without installing it to your drivers. So basically, you run Ubuntu from USB.**

**If you have problem opening your disk from Ubuntu even if you see them:**

Open terminal and write

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to list disks, /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb2, etc.

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

Will allow you to open the disk from file manager. If not, try restarting.

**If even with reaching the disk, you can't seem to be finding your files:**

I was mainly looking for my Baldur's Gate 3 saves (77 hours I have put in for that character ) But they were not in the folder. So for that you can search from terminal with

```
find /media/mydisk1 -type f -iname "*.lsv*"
```

lsv is the extension for BG3 save files. You can write anything you remember from the files you are searching `*` characters allows to find similar texts.After searching, found files would be stored in a folder, like `found.000` which will be in that USB you booted Ubuntu from. Now you can copy those files even though they are not visible in file explorer/manager. And they work.